# XNA make sprite follow the mouse pointer but with a delay?

Tags: c#, xna

Here I updated my code with your help.
Anyway it still does not do what is supposed to do, following the mouse pointer with a delay.

The balloon (the sprite) is flying diagonally and does not stop once the mouse pointer is met, only slows down then keeps moving and then speeds up.
I added an if condition once the balloonPosition is equal to mouse pointer, to have the velocity = 0, but that does not stop the balloon.

I added a portion of code for keeping the balloon (the sprite) in the screen.

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
    //balloonPosition = new Vector2(currentMouseState.X, currentMouseState.Y);
    //System.Windows.Input.MouseState currentMouseState = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetState();
    // Get the current mouse position
    Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(currentMouseState.X, currentMouseState.Y);
    // Get the distance between the balloon and the mouse.
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(mousePosition, balloonPosition);
    // You can change the standard velocity / or the max distance to make the sprite move faster or slower.
    // Currently it may move to fast or to slow for you to know a difference. 
    balloonVelocity = StandardVelocity * (distance/MaxDistance);
    // Set the balloons position to the new velocity.
    balloonPosition += balloonVelocity;

    if (balloonPosition == mousePosition)
    {
       balloonVelocity = new Vector2(0);
    }
    //Keep the balloon in the screen
    if (balloonPosition.X < balloon.Width / 2)
        balloonPosition.X = balloon.Width / 2;
    if (balloonPosition.Y < balloon.Height / 2)
        balloonPosition.Y = balloon.Height / 2;
    if (balloonPosition.X > Window.ClientBounds.Width - balloon.Width / 2)
        balloonPosition.X = Window.ClientBounds.Width - balloon.Width / 2;
    if (balloonPosition.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height - balloon.Height / 2)
        balloonPosition.Y = Window.ClientBounds.Height;

}
```

Comment: As I keep saying there are 3 different things. Speed difference or delay difference or both. You keep saying you need a delay but when you explain you need a speed difference. Which one do you actually need ? I already showed you how to make a difference in speed based on distance from mouse to balloon with the below answer. I also explained in that answer how to make a time delay but I did not make any code for it. The balloon will almost never be equal to the mouse pointer. I updated code below as I forgot to set the velocity.

Answer (score 1):

```
NewPosition = Vector2.Lerp(CurrentPosition, DesiredPosition, Speed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list or an array to keep the delay. Store the mouse position every 0.03125 seconds in a list. Then set timer for the delay (integer counter should work). When the delay is up start reading from the list at the same pace it was out in the list. (0.03125 in this case) and move your sprite towards that point.

Since you are looking for how to change the speed this is one way to do it.

```
    Vector2 balloonOrigin, balloonPosition;
    Vector2 balloonVelocity;
    private float MaxDistance = 1920; // Reduce this value to slow down the balloon.

    public static float AngleBetweenVectors(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2) { return (float)Math.Atan2(v2.Y - v1.Y, v2.X - v1.X); }

    public void test()
    {
        //System.Windows.Input.MouseState currentMouseState = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetState();
        // Get the current mouse position
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(currentMouseState.X, currentMouseState.Y);
        // Get the distance between the balloon and the mouse.
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(mousePosition, balloonPosition);
        // You can change the max distance to make the sprite move faster or slower.
        // Currently it may move to fast or to slow for you to know a difference. 
        balloonVelocity = AngleBetweenVectors(balloonPosition, mousePosition) * (distance / MaxDistance);
        // Set the balloons position to the new velocity.
        balloonPosition += balloonVelocity;
    }
```

Comment: It might be better to use the natural loop of `Update` rather than your own timer.

Comment: @gunr2171 That is wha I meant when saying use an integer counter. I always call anything that counts time a timer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is there any better way? I mean without using the list or array, instead using the hint that I have with a "vector velocity".

Comment: Velocity alone cannot offer a delay. List is the best option to go in my opinion. You can easily store and retrieve vectors.

Comment: I doubt that it cannot be done this way, because the book suggested to use this hint with the velocity: "add a balloon velocity vector to the program and change the velocity depending on the distance of the balloon to the mouse pointer."

Comment: Are you talking about the speed at which the sprite moves ? If you are then you multiply the vector by a value. .5 for half speed. You can get distance between and divide the distance then multiply by that value to get a changing speed based on distance from your sprite.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement that.

Comment: I just told you how to implement it. I will try to post example code when I get home so you can better

Comment: Thank you, that will help me very much.

Comment: @Light_Warrior I updated the post. It should work for what you need.

Comment: We are getting close but still it doesn't work as supposed I updated my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd go with off the top of my head:

```
public List<Tuple<TimeSpan, Vector2>> Points { get; set; }

public Vector2 CurrentPoint { get; set; }

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Points.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, Vector2>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), mouseCoords));

    foreach(var point in Points)
    {
        point.Item1 -= gameTime.ElapsedTimeSpan;

        if (point.Item1 < TimeSpan.Zero)point
            CurrentPoint = point.Item2;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I wouldn't need to explain the code, right?
In the draw loop, you'd simply always draw the CurrentPoint